# What is right to use Spread operator or Object.assign in Redux?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, flux, react-redux

I had a little bit of confusion whether to use Spread operator or  Object.assign in reducer function to apply changes to the target object.

```
const toggleTodo = (todo) => {
  return Object.assign({}, todo, {
    completed: !todo.completed
   });
 };
```

Then above mention code is using Object.assign method, and the below one is using spread operator

```
const toggleTodo = (todo) => {
return {
  ...todo,
  completed: !todo.completed
  };
};
```

Which is the appropriate method in both of these

Comment: What does "appropriate" term mean? If it works - it's appropriate, if it does not - it's not.

Comment: both are working fine, but i want to know which is right method to implement

Comment: There is no absolute "right" way to do anything.

Comment: thanks you @zerkms

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The object spread operator (`...`) doesn't work in browsers, because it isn't part of any ES specification yet, just [a proposal](https://github.com/sebmarkbage/ecmascript-rest-spread1). The only option is to compile it with Babel (or something similar).

Here's the compiled code from [Babel's REPL](http://babeljs.io/repl).

```
var _extends = Object.assign || /* a polyfill */;

return _extends({}, todo, {
  completed: !todo.completed
});
```

As you can see, it's just syntactic sugar over `Object.assign({})`.

There's no *right* option.

As far as I can see, these are the important differences.

- `Object.assign` works in most browsers (without compiling)
- `...` for objects isn't standardized
- `...` protects you from accidentally mutating the object
- `...` will polyfill Object.assign in browsers without it
- `...` needs less code to express the same idea

Comment: http://stefan.magnuson.co/articles/frontend/using-es7-spread-operator-with-webpack/ http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/UsingObjectSpreadOperator.html